# How to bind click event to already rendered dynamically added select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to add a click event to an already rendered select2 dropdown menu. The select2 is dynamically added to the page on load. Is this possible? I've tried adding it to the div class and many other classes, but it's not responding.

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-auto-width select2-drop-active" style="left: 394.375px; top: 1289.56px; bottom: auto; display: block; width: auto;" id="select2-drop">
    <div class="select2-search select2-search-hidden select2-offscreen">
        <label for="s2id_autogen143_search" class="select2-offscreen"> </label>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-143" id="s2id_autogen143_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-191"> </div>
    <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-143">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
            <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-191" role="option"> <span class="select2-match"> </span>the same time:</div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
            <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-192" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span> a different time: </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried versions of this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#select2-drop', function () {
  alert('wow');
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#select2-drop', function () {
  alert('wow');
});
```

I'm currently using this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
```

Comment: you are welcome, please add the code you tried for adding the event so others can help you more easily

Comment: Not sure what your ultimate objective is but `select2` triggers a number of events that you may be able to use without adding another listener. See [Select2: Events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events)

Comment: I've looked at that. It looks like I need the id/class of the `select` before it was converted to select2. I don't know that id/class. `$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  // Do something
});`

Comment: I want to display a message when the form is changed (or clicked on is okay too).

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here with your event handling?

Comment: I'm working on a WordPress plugin. The plugin affects the functionality of a form within an admin screen. I want to show a message if the user changes the form. The sections of the form are dynamically created on page load and unpredictable what will be there and each section can contain select2 dropdowns. I have some experience adding events to dynamically generated elements in jquery, but this is not working. So my ultimate goal is to display a message when any form element is either changed or clicked. I don't need to hide the message if the form values are actually not changed.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to accomplish what you are looking for, but you may get better eyes and sound ideas on accomplishing your plugin goals, if you visit https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and post the question there.  When working with forms in WordPress, you may get better support there, especially if you want it done right.

Comment: @klewis thanks. I was thinking about that but I think this is more about generic jquery/select2 than specially WordPress.